# How to 'remove' the "&" symbol when running python files in VSCode

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code

So I recently downloaded vscode and git bash, so I am relatively new.

I made a regular python file in vscode and downloaded the python extension for vscode which gives the little 'run' button on the top right. I set my default terminal to Git Bash. But when I press the run button *(for python specifically, for java it doesn't even run on Git Bash, and I haven't tested any other language because I am only familiar with these 2)*, I get this error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&`

For some reason, it puts a `&` before executing the command like this

````
& C:/Users/savar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/savar/1. Savar/VSCodeDirectory/School/helloworld.py"```
````

Is there a way to fix this? (Just to be clear, if I run it manually using `python [file_name].py` it does work and even just

```
C:/Users/savar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/savar/1. Savar/VSCodeDirectory/School/helloworld.py"
```

(without the `&`)

[Here is what my vscode looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uED7C.png)

Comment: Clearly, you need to check through the settings/preferences for that extension.  Somewhere, it's doing this substitution.  Perhaps it though it was running another command first.

Comment: We've gotten a _lot_ of copies of this question asked inside recent weeks. This is very, very duplicative. Unfortunately, none of the people having the problem have ever described how to make someone _not_ have the problem how to set their copy of VS Code up so it exhibits the issue, so AFAICT every instance has been closed as lacking a [mre].

Comment: One (deleted, so not visible to everyone) is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321435/why-is-visual-studio-code-putting-a-when-i-try-to-run-my-code-with-the-run-b

Comment: So you are saying that there is no solution to this? (Besides using powershell/doing it manually)

Comment: No known solution that I've seen, but then, I also haven't seen the question asked with enough details to allow the problem to be reproduced; without a [mre] telling someone how to configure their system to cause the problem, answers can't be reliably tested, so it's impossible to know if those answers are correct.